# application loader / window builder

Tags: windows, batch-file, user-interface, cmd

Long time reader of posts first time posting, firstly thanks for a great site I couldn’t do my job without this site half the time.

My question is I currently have a batch file that I run on our clients that maps network drives copy files from the server to a Ram drive 
And then runs the application code below. What I need to do is replace this with a nice looking GUI window. I have looked at some task automation apps (vtask studio, winautomation, visual cron) but none have the ability to create a window.
Ideally the start up would go something like, welcome to loader ping the server if it gets a reply then continues with the file copy a progress bar would be great.
Essentially build a nice looking application loader I’m running window 7 pro on the clients Windows server 2008 R2 for the server.

Any and all suggestions gratefully received thanks in advance !

Code:

```
:START 
@echo off
TIMEOUT /T 15
NET USE m: /delete
NET USE n: /delete
NET USE n: \\SERVER\Apps 
NET USE m: \\SERVER\Media 
NET USE l: \\SERVER\Logs
MD d:\Apps
XCOPY n:\*.* d:\Apps\ /Y /H /E /B
TIMEOUT /T 5
mklink /D C:\Apps D:\Apps
TIMEOUT /T 5
START /MIN /WAIT "Launcher" "C:\Apps\shortcuts\Launcher.Lnk"
START /MIN E:\PY.BAT
TIMEOUT /T 10
START /MIN "reader" "C:\Apps\shortcuts\Reader.Lnk"
TIMEOUT /T 5
:LAUNCH
ECHO %Time% %Date% "Launching Application"  >>"%MyLogFile%"
START /MIN /WAIT "Launcher" "C:\Apps\applications\Launch.lnk" 
GOTO LAUNCH
```

Comment: Hi David thanks for your input I have looked at the link you have given but this seems to be for web based scripting ?? the application I'm launching is a executable java jar. sorry if I was not clear with my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do ALL of these steps in a single vTask script.
Mounting / unmounting network drives, copying files, and even displaying simple GUIs that you control.
Certainly there is a progress bar command and it works well.
vTask is probably the easiest way to build a simple GUI, put actual code behind it (including SQL etc.) and even call .DLLs if needed.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I know that [VisualCron](http://www.visualcron.com) (that you mentioned) has the Popup Task which can ask questions or provide information in a window before doing somethign (like starting a Task) with any parameters you supply in that window.